# Одновременная анимация нескольких Views

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Каждый раз при нажатии на экран - появляется новая `View`, каждая `View`  должна постоянно смещаться влево, сейчас у меня при добавлении новой `View` останавливается анимация для предыдущей `View`. Как сделать, что бы все анимации работали одновременно?

```
 private class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            switch (e.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    int x = (int) e.getX();
                    int y = (int) e.getY();

                    draw = new DrawView(getActivity(), 1, String.valueOf(xcoordList.size()));
                    drawViewList.add(draw);
                    progressBar.addView(draw);
                    progressBar.invalidate();

                    drawViewList.get(drawViewList.size()-1).animate().translationXBy(-360f).setDuration(1000);

                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000 - timeList.get(0), 1000) {
                                int j = 3;
                                @Override
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    final DrawView drawView = drawViewList.get(drawViewList.size()-1);

                            drawView.animate().translationXBy((-720f)/j).setDuration(1000);
                                    j++;

                                @Override
                                public void onFinish() {

                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    };

                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение, которое применила, заменила данную строку:

```
drawView.animate().translationXBy((-720f)/j).setDuration(1000);
```

на:

```
 drawView.animate().translationXBy((-720f)/j)
                                        .setDuration(1000).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                                        j++;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                        drawView.animate().translationXBy((-720f) / j).setDuration(1000);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                                    }
                                });
```